# Не появляется анимация по возвращению на контроллер

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

Не появляется анимация кнопки по возвращению на контроллер с этой кнопкой. При первом запуске кнопка анимируется как надо. По нажатию на нее переходим на др контроллер. По возвращению на контроллер с кнопкой анимации нет, хотя условие анимации не меняется, с каким была тэгом, с таким и осталась ))

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   animateCurrentLevel()
}

func animateCurrentLevel() {

   if let button = scrollView.viewWithTag(levelsDone + 1) {

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,.autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations:
        { button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)}, completion: nil)

       scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(button.frame.insetBy(dx: -200, dy: -200), animated: true)
   }
}
```

Comment: Хотя сначала уточнить, как осуществляется переход и возврат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте completion:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)}, completion: { (_) -> Void in
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!